# Attempted import error: 'colorChannel' is not exported from '@mui/system'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

in my react project getting this error.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/experimental_extendTheme.js
Attempted import error: 'colorChannel' is not exported from '@mui/system'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to show us the code